# How to use Vectors to find the centroid of a tetrahedron?

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d, solid-geometry, centroid

Suppose that four points - A,B,C,D (with position vectors a,b,c,d) are the vertices of a tetrahedron. And the mid points of BC, CA, AB, AD, BD, CD are denoted by P,Q,R,U,V,W.

Using these info, I tried finding the centroid by finding the mid-point of vectors PU, QV and RW. But it isn't working out for me.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Well, don't keep us in suspense! Why isn't it working out? What have you got so far?

Comment: From the mid point of PU, I am getting (a+d-c-b)/4. But I know that's not correct.

Comment: $CM =({\bf A} + {\bf B} + {\bf C} + {\bf D})/4$.

Comment: Nvm, figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

The centroid is $(a+b+c+d)/4$. You don't need the midpoints of the sides.

You might understand this better if you think about the centroid of a triangle. It lies $2/3$ of the way along the median from each vertex.

Comment: Yes, but i wanted to know how to find the centroid via vectors and the midpoints.

Comment: That calculation does use vectors. Midpoints are less relevant than you think,  They don't help much with triangles so why expect them to with tetrahedra?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can take: $\frac{P+U}{2}$ or $\frac{Q+V}{2}$ or $\frac{R+W}{2}.$